# Is there a way to reference individual instantiated cloned objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I instantiate multiple instances of the same, lets say, ball object and there ends up being 20 balls, how do I reference one specifically? For example, if I wanted to change the color of one ball clone, destroy a specific clone, or get access to an individual ball clone's specific variables that are attached to it, how would I go about doing that?

All cloned objects just appear in the hierarchy as "ballgameobject(clone)". Is there a way to tell them apart?

Answer (score 1):

You can give each Ball a unique identifier during their initialization.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Guid Id => id;
}
```

This id can then be used to uniquely identify specific ball instances.

```
public class BallManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, Ball> instances = new Dictionary<Guid, Ball>();

    public Ball CreateBall(Ball prefab)
    {
        var result = Object.Instantiate(prefab);
        instances[result.Id] = result;
        return result;
    }

    public void SetBallColor(Guid ballId, Color color)
    {
        instances[ballId].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
    }

    public void DestroyBall(Guid ballId)
    {
        Object.Destroy(instances[ballId]);
        instances.Remove(ballId);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: If the id does not need to persist between sessions then you could actually also just use [Object.GetInstanceID()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html).

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, Ball> instances = new Dictionary<int, Ball>();

public Ball CreateBall(Ball prefab)
{
    var result = Object.Instantiate(prefab);
    instances[result.GetInstanceID()] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're working in Unity. You can do this with each individual gameObject in Unity. You should also rename them all in Unity so that they can be told apart.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the clones in an array to reference then later like this:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject ball = new GameObject("Ball");   
    GameObject[] clones = new GameObject[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        clones[i] = GameObject.Instantiate(ball);
        clones[i].name = $"Ball_{i}";
    }

    //With the array indexer you can access each clone and can do whatever you want with it.
    Destroy(clones[5]); // Destroys the fifth gameobject
}
```

Comment: I thought of using an array previously but I realized that it would not work for my situation since the ball objects will be constantly destroyed and instantiated(yes, they need to be destroyed and not just disabled) which would would mess up the array order. So if, let's say, clone 8 is the one that I want to change color but clone 4 and 3 got destroyed, clone 8 will no longer be clone 8 when I need to reference it.

Comment: What about using a dictionary, as key you could use the name of the ball, which should be unique like in my for loop and then you can access each ball by its name. With that you don't have the rpoblem with the order.